# Best practice: Twig logic versus Preprocess functions

Tags: 8, theming

I use Twig and [Twig Tweak](https://git.drupalcode.org/project/twig_tweak) to do most of the processing. However, from time to time I need to rely on Preprocess functions to get the desired result.

This led me to a situation where now most of my variables are created in a Preprocess function before handing them over to Twig (this keeps my templates clean, simple and most of all easy to read). I also don't like my code being scattered between Templates and Theme functions.

But regarding [Drupal Documentation](https://www.drupal.org/docs/theming-drupal/twig-in-drupal/using-custom-content-types-and-fields-with-twig#s-example), this method seems discouraged.

> ```
> function mytheme_preprocess_node(&$variable) {
>  if ($variable['node']->getType() === 'my_content_type_machine_name') {
>  $variable['my_title'] = $variable['node']->field_my_title->value;
>  }
> }
> ```
>
> You may now use the more concise `{{ my_title }}` in your twig file to
> refer to `{{ node->field_my_title->value }}`.
>
> However, while this might be possible, **it is discouraged** to create
> new variables in this manner. Using `{{ node.field_my_title.value }}`
> is fairly reasonable to type and avoids any potential issues and
> should be preferred.

So basically my question is: Are there any simple rules to follow regarding Twig versus Preprocess functions for additional logic?

Comment: I'm with you. But it's an opinion-based thing. How ugly does that look when you have `{{ file_url(content.field_custom_image[0]['#media'].field_media_image.entity.uri.value) }}` with maybe a couple of ifs and else around it when you could simple preprocess it and have `{{ my_file_url }}` instead? In my opinion templates should be kept clean and logic should be kept out of them. Heavy templating involves the danger of invalidating the UI. I find it important that the UI is kept intact and instead use custom field formatters, view modes and pseudo/extra fields which can be set in the backend.

Comment: @leymannx, this is indeed a bad example, because this is referencing a render array and not an object like in the linked documentation.

Comment: I agree and don't like code scattered between preprocess and templates - you're always going to have to make a judgement call for what's right in a situation. You can always help mitigate any confusion about where a variable is created by clearly documenting it in your twig template, e.g. `my_special_var: Special var, see my_module_preprocess()` - you see this in core's twig templates.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is documented in the node template. These are the two most important variables:

```
* Available variables:
 * - node: The node entity with limited access to object properties and methods.
 *   Only method names starting with "get", "has", or "is" and a few common
 *   methods such as "id", "label", and "bundle" are available. For example:
 *   - node.getCreatedTime() will return the node creation timestamp.
 *   - node.hasField('field_example') returns TRUE if the node bundle includes
 *     field_example. (This does not indicate the presence of a value in this
 *     field.)
 *   - node.isPublished() will return whether the node is published or not.
 *   Calling other methods, such as node.delete(), will result in an exception.
 *   See \Drupal\node\Entity\Node for a full list of public properties and
 *   methods for the node object.
 * - label: (optional) The title of the node.
 * - content: All node items. Use {{ content }} to print them all,
 *   or print a subset such as {{ content.field_example }}. Use
 *   {{ content|without('field_example') }} to temporarily suppress the printing
 *   of a given child element.
```

It clearly states that you should print the render array `{{ content }}` and use the object `{{ node }}` with its properties and methods to get the node data you need.